# Binary search a vector in chunks

Tags: rust, binary-search

I have a file of ipv4 addresses, which as we know are 4 bytes each. I wish to do a binary search over the file contents to find a given IP address. Rust has a built-in binary search but it doesn't let you pass a len and it instead reads it from the vector.

I have tried to adapt the built-in rust binary search but am a bit lost. This is where i am so far. Maybe there is a way to use the built in method?

```
fn binary_search(s: &Vec<&u8>, x: &u32) -> Result<usize, usize> {
    let f = |p: &[u8]| p.cmp(x); // need to compare byte slices somehow

    let mut size = s.len() / 4;
    if size == 0 {
        return Err(0);
    }
    let mut base = 0usize;
    while size > 1 {
        let half = size / 2;
        let mid = base + half;

        let cmp = f(s[mid..mid+4]);

        base = if cmp == Greater { base } else { mid };
        size -= half;
    }

    let cmp = f(s[base..base+4]);

    if cmp == Equal {
        Ok(base)
    } else {
        Err(base + (cmp == Less) as usize)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why a `&Vec<&u8>` instead of a `&[[u8; 4]]`?

Comment: Good question. I'm really new to rust, not sure what &[u8; 4] denotes. I've posted a seemingly working solution now, but it might not be idiomatic rust.

Answer (score 1):

It’d be better to have a slice with one element per address, either of 4-byte arrays (`[u8; 4]`), some equivalent struct (hey, `Ipv4Addr`), or just `u32`. Unfortunately, I don’t think it’s possible to reinterpret a `&[u8]` with a length divisible by 4 as `&[[u8; 4]]` yet (and the other options would need alignment). You could do this conversion while reading the file in chunks, though.

So first, in an equivalent example program:

```rust
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;

fn main() {
    let vec: Vec<Ipv4Addr> = vec![
        [10, 0, 0, 0].into(),
        [20, 0, 0, 0].into(),
        [30, 0, 0, 0].into(),
    ];
    println!("vec {:?}", vec);

    let found = vec.binary_search(&Ipv4Addr::from_str("20.0.0.0").unwrap());

    println!("found {:?}", found);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=56fb91280d81adbc0525268836cb8143)

Then reading from a file would look something like:

```rust
let mut vec: Vec<Ipv4Addr> = vec![];

loop {
    let mut address = [0; 4];

    match f.read_exact(&mut address) {
        Ok(()) => {},
        Err(err) if err.kind() == ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof => break,
        err => err?,
    }

    vec.push(address.into());
}
```

(although this one is *slightly* lax in that it ignores any trailing bytes that don’t form a multiple of 4)

where `f` is a `BufReader` around a file.

Comment: "It’d be better to have a slice with one element per address". Agree with that, but not possible if ur reading from a file as i am.

Comment: @user2626526: The second half of the answer is about how to read those from a file, though…

Comment: I see. I get the approach but i think there would be too many allocations here as im reading millions of IPs. The approach i've posted lets me use include_bytes and keep allocations to a minimum

Comment: @user2626526: There would be very few allocations (O(log n), even fewer if you start with a capacity estimate). Copies, sure, but you might be surprised at how little that matters with millions. I expect searches to be faster than your current solution, but maybe less if the `to_vec()`s are removed :)

Answer (score 0):

I think i have a working solution now, but i'm not a master at rust so please critique it harshly.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6e3102ea622f1ae0d66465f4007ccb03

```
use std::cmp::Ordering::{self, Equal, Greater, Less};
use std::net::{IpAddr, Ipv4Addr, Ipv6Addr};
use std::str::FromStr;

fn binary_search(s: Vec<u8>, x: Vec<u8>) -> Result<usize, usize> {
    let f = |p: &[u8]| p.cmp(&x);

    let mut size = s.len() / 4;
    if size == 0 {
        return Err(0);
    }
    let mut base = 0usize;
    while size > 1 {
        let half = size / 2;
        let mid = base + half;

        // mid is always in [0, size), that means mid is >= 0 and < size.
        // mid >= 0: by definition
        // mid < size: mid = size / 2 + size / 4 + size / 8 ...

        let cmp = f(s[mid*4..(mid+1)*4].to_vec());

        base = if cmp == Greater { base } else { mid };
        size -= half;
    }
    // base is always in [0, size) because base <= mid.
    let cmp = f(s[base*4..(base+1)*4].to_vec());


    if cmp == Equal {
        Ok(base*4)
    } else {
        Err(base*4 + ((cmp == Less) as usize) * 4)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec: Vec<u8> = vec![10, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0];
    println!("vec {:?}", vec);

    let found = binary_search(vec, Ipv4Addr::from_str("20.0.0.0").unwrap().octets().to_vec());

    println!("found {:?}", found);
}
```